# Query objects From Parse localDataStore

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm busy trying to query items I'm storing im my Parse `localDataStore`.
There is 6 fields that I'm storing in my `LocationLogs` class (Parse class)/.
These fields are image, Lat, long, altitude, title, description. When storing them directly into Parse via

```
    locationLogs["longitude"] = location.longitude
    locationLogs["latitude"] = location.latitude
    locationLogs["altitude"] = altitude
    locationLogs.saveInBackgroundWithBlock { (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (success) {

        }else{

        }
    }
```

It works perfectly. But when using `locationLogs.pinInBackground()` and then trying to query it with

```
 let query = PFQuery(className:"LocatinLogs")
    query.fromLocalDatastore()
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock( { (NSArray results, NSError error) in
        // do something

        println("count = \(results!.count)")

    })
```

The `count` stays = nil.

What query method must I use? The template code Parse.com provides gives an Error for the block.

Comment: Two things you might want to check out: 1) did you check if pinning actually succeeds? 2) If the objects you are pinning do have an ACL, you need to tell the query to ignore the ACL when running the query (see https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/ignoreACLs)

Comment: How do I check to see if it pinned correctly

Comment: Call `pinInBackgroundWithBlock` which should include an error parameter, this would tell you if there were any errors when pinning, see https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/pinInBackgroundWithBlock:

Comment: I did and there is no error available , I still feel like it is the syntax of my query method. Or does it look viable?

Comment: Did you check (2) of my suggestions yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a spelling Error:

```
  let query = PFQuery(className:"LocatinLogs")
```

The Class that you query is Spelt wrong.
That will fix your error (:
It happens to the best of us trust me!!

Answer (score 0):

Save the object and pin it on success. Until an object is saved (or pushed to `saveEventually` IIRC) it doesn't have an `objectId` and isn't considered as a 'valid' object (for instance you also can't add it to a relationship).